# Is it correct to add styles like properties in a React Native View element?

Tags: react-native

I've been working with RN using Views with styles added in the style tag, but yesterday I found out that I could add the same style but as a property, for example:

```
<View style={{marginTop: 20}} />
```

is the same as:

```
<View marginTop={20} />
```

I don't know why the docs didn't say anything about it.

Is it deprecated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This actually works? I just checked the typescript definitions and margin is not listed as a property for View.

If you read the docs for View though it says View should be used with Stylesheet.

[image]

As for if this is deprecated... I'm not sure.  Sounds like you found some loop hole if adding styles directly to the component actually works.

Comment: Yes, is working. Even I tried to compile this and uploaded to stores, everything is working well. But, maybe I just need to follow the docs. ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not deprecated. You can read more about layout-props here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#margintop

For more complicated styling of a component, I would always prefer "style" but it could make sense to use if you have a number of almost similar components where only one or a few style-properties are different. E.g. with a list of cards in different colours. You can have the general style in the "style"-prop and then set the unique color in a "background-color"-prop.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. But is weird because, if you check the code snippet on the above link, all the view tags have only the style-prop.

Comment: @CarlosGarcía yes, that is because it's the documentation for Layout Props. If you go here (https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props) you will see the documentation for normal view-styling :-)

Answer (score -1):

View component have a style prop in which we can pass our styleSheet custom object. View don't have style properties as a prop.

We can only pass the prop to the child component.